# Signing Code (windows binaries) platform for systemhouse

Tags: jenkins, code-signing

We are signing our code (windows binaries) with key signed by trusted CA.

I don't like the idea that every developer has the crt+key and there is no control what has been signed. I also don't like the idea of CI (jenkins) that auto signs every binary.

I'm looking for a centralized solution to sign code with auditing (so I will know what and by who has been signed). Perfect would be to have a way that requires ACK from at least two members of managers group.

How that process is organized in your companies? What is the proper solution backed by best practices?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a list in any SCM to track which files you're signing, and using git even makes it easier to see who added files to the list. working with pull requests will solve your acknowledge issue and any scripting language can easily solve your issue with a simple wrapper on your code signing service.